# WAMP server: localhost/mysite shows blank page - Bad migration from one pc to another

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin

A friend gave  me half created site in wordpress in order to finish it. I've installed wamp, set apache port to 8080, import site db in phpmyadmin, and when i type in browser

```
 localhost:8080
```

I get this http://prntscr.com/cgw45i screen.
When I type `localhost:8080/phpmyadmin` I get transfered to phpmyadmin page.
But when i type `localhost:8080/wordpress` (wordpress is folder name in wamp/www where  site is located) , `localhost:8080/wordpress` transforms into `http://localhost/wordpress/en/home/`, and blank page shows. 
Tried to change

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

but nothing happens.
And when I install wordpress into new folder and run it, it works. Then I tried to copy files from wordpress folder to site folder(in site folder I've installed new wordpress, but still no success).
I've added

```
define('WP_HOME','localhost/site'); // also tried with localhost:8080/site
define('WP_SITEURL','localhost/site');
```

to wp-config.php , but than just transfers me to localhost/site/en...
It is just like that somewhere in code he try to assign his old address...

Comment: have you properly installed wordpress to your wamp local server?

Comment: No, I've copied entire install folder from him, and follow this http://www.wpexplorer.com/migrating-wordpress-website/, and this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/187922/how-to-transfer-wordpress-folder-from-one-pc-to-another 
Site worked fine on his computer

Comment: Sorry, but the information is _far_ to fuzzy for us to say anything. You did not do a propper isntallation but _somehow_ copied _something_. You really expect us to be able to point to something specific here?

Answer (score 1):

it's an error. you most likely have `display_errors = 0 / Off` in `php.ini`. and when an error is unhandled, page rendering is terminated. because Wordpress uses output buffering to render its pages, if an error is raised (and not handled) before the buffer is echoed, you get a white page.  if `log_errors` is disabled, enable it. then check the php error log, as defined in the `error_log` php.ini directive, it should contain the error which you need to fix, to get the page to render.

Answer (score 0):

- Have you tried to go directly to `http://localhost/wordpress` without being redirected from `localhost:8080/wordpress`?
- Are you sure that all the files required by wordpress are present (especially an `index.php` file in your `wamp/www/wordpress` folder?
- Is MySQL up and running?
- Maybe (if the site is half-built) you are missing some settings in the `wp-config.php` file, especially this part (which defines the DB parameters) :

```
    define('DB_NAME', 'database_name_here');
    define( 'DB_USER', 'username_here' );
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Comment: All of this values are set, and MySQL is up running on port 3306
index.php is present in wordpress folder

Answer (score 0):

Check out what headers are sent to you.

```
curl -v -XGET 'http://localhost:8080'
```

My guess is that wordpress is setup to another host, and so tries to redirect to whatever host your friend was using.

If that is the case, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

You should also provide more information. What is Apache error_log saying?

Comment: I've changed site url but now error shows http://prntscr.com/cgwp80
This is Apache error_log (part, it is same for different time values) 

http://prntscr.com/cgwq2a